# The action you have requested is invalid on search with no result

Tags: search, simple-search

I am using the simple search form on EE 2.8.1 with the following tag:

```
{exp:search:simple_form
                    channel="blog|products|faq"
                    where="any"
                    results="20"
                    form_class="et-search-form et-hidden"
                    no_result_page="/search/"
                    result_page="/search/results"

                }
                <input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="keywords" title="Search for:">
                {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

The form works as intended when there is a search result. If there is no search result the form will throw the error "**The action you have requested is invalid**".

Removing the **no_result_page** parameter will result in EE showing me "Your search did not return any results." message.

I suspect the secure form submission issue and included

```
 <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">
```

But no luck.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your no search results parameter to include the index template of that group

```
no_result_page="search/index"
```

The parameter should include the template group and template:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/simple.html#no-result-page

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work either.

Comment: Thank you! I came upon this error and found I had my template name misspelled for my no_result_page="" parameter

Comment: I think you also have to have a designated no results template.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work, and not get the "The action you have requested is invalid" message when there are no results, I also had to set the template in the no_result_page parameter to a different template than the result_page template.

On further investigation, however, it seems that the problem specifically lies with the EE search engine returning "no results" and loading a template that uses the {exp:search:search_results} tag. (So, potentially, you could re-use the same template if you had some sort of conditional.)